# How to show/hide HTML Buttons via MVC Action Method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my web page, I need to populate button according to parameter value called `ButtonType`.
let's say that If `ButtonType == "Edit"` then I need to hide every buttons but `butUpdate`.

I want to know how to show/hide html buttons via MVC Action method.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SupplierDetail(int SupplierID, string ButtonType)
    {   
        var Supplier = supplierListRepository.Supplier_SelectByID(SupplierID);
        return View(Supplier);
    }
```

I am using Asp.net Mvc Razor form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SupplierDetail_SubmitClick", "Supplier", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmSupplierDetail" }))
{   
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:450px; height:auto">
.....
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" id="butSave" name="butSave" value="Save" style="width:100px; height:auto" />
        <input type="submit" id="butUpdate" name="butUpdate" value="Update" style="width:100px; height:auto" />
        <input type="submit" id="butDelete" name="butDelete" value="Delete" style="width:100px; height:auto" />
        <input type="submit" id="butReset" name="butReset" value="Reset" style="width:100px; height:auto" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="content">
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

}
```

Every Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Appricated in The same sense that you have appreciated the answers for the 20+ question where you didn't bother to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your controller add the buttontype to viewdata:

```
ViewData["ButtonType"] = ButtonType
```

Then, in the view itself, you can add if/else statements, or any other logic that suits all of ur cases, to decide what to render:

```
@if (ViewData["ButtonType"].ToString() == "Edit")
{
    <input type="submit" id="butUpdate" name="butUpdate" value="Update"    
     style="width:100px; height:auto" />      
}
```

Of course,  this is but a demo of what can be done, Yuo should adapt the code to ur buisness logics

Answer (score 2):

It is not a controller action responsibility to show/hide buttons. A controller action doesn't/shouldn't even know what a button means. That's a concept that exists on the view. A controller action on the other hand is supposed to communicate with the model and prepare a view model that it passes to the view for displaying. So you could define a view model that will contain properties defining the visibility of the buttons and based on the value of the ButtonType parameter set those properties accordingly. Then the controller action will pas this view model to the view instead of the `supplier` object that you are currently passing. Obviously the view model will also have a property to hold this supplier. Now all that's left for the view is based on the values of the view model properties decide how to display the buttons.